# I am getting a VBA run time error 438 when using ThisWorkbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to import information from one excel file (File x) into another (File y). File x has 40+ sheets in it. I only want to copy some of the sheets (Ex. 5,6,7,8,15,17 etc.)

I am not sure how to fix the run time error using `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets`

```
Sub Get_Data_From_File()

    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim OpenBook As Workbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import Range", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")

    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        OpenBook.Sheets("January").Range("A1:H20").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("January").Range("A1").Paste
        OpenBook.Close False
    
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: There's no `Range.Paste` method ... this has nothing to do with `ThisWorkbook`. Either use `PasteSpecial` as demonstrated in the linked thread, or just use `OpenBook.Sheets("January").Range("A1:H20").Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("January").Range("A1")`.

Comment: Can you explain how to use Destination:=

I am getting a compile error the way I tried to use it

Comment: It should be on the same line as the `Copy`